# VirtualBox DNS Specific Port Forwarding

Tags: virtualbox, dns, port-forwarding, nat

Here is my problem;

I have virtual-box running on Ubuntu 64 bit (17.04) and I have multiple virtual machines (all Ubuntu 64 bit).

I want to forward port 80, 25, 143 and 22 to all of the virtual machines, dns name specific.

For example;

```
ssh username@domain-1 --> domain-1-virtual_machine port 22

ssh username@domain-2 --> domain-2_virtual_machine port 22
```

etc.

I want that a request from domain-1 on a specific port will go to vm1 and a request from domain-2 on the same port will go to vm2.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding is so easy when you select NAT network in Virtualbox.

[image]

Host and Guest IP are assigned as base machine and VirtualBox IP respectively, so as in ports.

[image]

Comment: but its not DNS name specific...

Comment: i know how to forward i just need it to be DNS specific

Comment: This exact setup as shown in the picture (substituting the guest machine's IP) doesn't work for me. If I forward to the guest port 21, 23, 80, 1014, 8022 (etc, just a few I've tried) it works. But when I use port 22 it doesn't. I checked with netstat, that nothing else listens on port 22 in the guest. Ubuntu 18.04 host, Ubuntu 22.04 guest, VirtualBox 7.0.8. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try Host only network and install [dnsmasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint) in your base machine to assign specific IP for each VM. Now you can easily append IP and host name of VMs in /etc/hosts file of base machine to connect to.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering, but im afraid you didnt understand my question.