# SSH into Virtual Machine from outside of NAT router

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables

I have a virtual machine on my host which I am trying to SSH from outside a NAT router. Both the host and the virtual machine are using the wifi interface and so have the same IP assigned by the home router. SSH is set for a different port on the VM and the host; I can thus SSH into either machine from the other locally, and I can SSH into the host from outside, but not the virtual machine. I would like to route traffic to a specific port (I have set this to 22000 on the virtual machine and home router) to the VM. Given that both have the same outside (and inside) IP; how do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: "*I can thus SSH into either machine from the other locally*" indicates that your Ubuntu system is likely configured correctly. The next test is to SSH into both Host and Guest from a third machine locally. After that, check your router's Port Forwarding - *both* ports (host and guest) need to be forwarded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no I can't SSH into the VM from another local machine; it appears to me that the request to connect is attempting to access the host on port 22000 rather than the VM and I need to forward traffic for that port to the VM from the host Yes, both ports 22 and 22000 are configured for port forwarding on the home router. I can obviously SSH into the host and then from the host SSH into the VM but it's a clumsy solution.

Comment: What networking method is your VM application using? NAT (default), Bridged? Something else? Is Ubuntu the Host or Guest or both?

Comment: VM is using NAT via virtual bridge and yes this was the default setting; both host and VM are using Ubunto. VM is running on KVM. Thanks

Comment: Did you remember to set up port forwarding on the Host? So the Host will forward Port 22000 to the Guest?

Comment: Ahh..that's the big question (-: .I have been searching for how to do this, but as yet to no avail. Thankyou

Comment: Here is [one way](https://superuser.com/questions/725318/nat-port-forwarding-in-virtualbox)

Comment: Here is [another way](https://superuser.com/questions/43822/virtualbox-nat-port-forwarding-on-ubuntu-64)

Comment: Your Google terms should include "ubuntu vm nat port forward"

Comment: Here is a [very specific answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/936339/19626) that seems to exactly address your problem.

Comment: I am using KVM rather than virtual box, but the discussion has clarified what I need to do. Will let you know if I get it working. Many thanks.