# Port seems open on Ubuntu Guest, I cannot connect to it from windows host using telnet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, postgresql, guest-os

I have the following: windows 10 host, ubuntu 18 guest. I want to connect to a postgresql instance on guest.

On guest:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN


postgres  649        postgres    7u  IPv4  20120      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
postgres  649        postgres    8u  IPv6  20121      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)

ip addr show

inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft 86074sec preferred_lft 86074sec
```

On host:

```
telnet 10.0.2.15 5432
Connecting To 10.0.2.15...Could not open connection to the host, on port 5432: Connect failed

ping 10.0.2.15

Pinging 10.0.2.15 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.2.15: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=62
Reply from 10.0.2.15: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=62
```

Any ideas?

Virtualbox network settings: I haven't touched these, don't know if I should. Here's a picture[image: Virtualbox network settings]

Firewall is disabled on both host and guest during testing.

Comment: Please add more details on how you've configured your network for this VM

Comment: See if this [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/936121/virtualbox-dns-specific-port-forwarding) help you with port forwarding in VirtualBox.  After you set to forward port 5432 of host's IP 127.0.01 to the same port of the guest IP 10.0.2.15, use the command `telnet 127.0.0.1 5432` from the host. If this works I will turn this comment to an answer, so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to desired port, allow it in your firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow 5432
```

Or you could even try

```
sudo ufw allow postgress
```

You could also configure configure your network connection using bridge, not NAT and check. But it is better to enable firewall and allow specific ports.

If you need to use NAT, then try to specify your port in Port Forwarding window, adding there `5432`:

[image]

Comment: btw I have already disabled the firewall